# Android BLE devices not detecting each other

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I am trying to use [Google's Sample BLE library](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt) to send data  between two LG Phoenix 4 phones, both running Android 7.1 and both BLE-compatible. I have successfully gotten the app onto both phones, but the phones cannot detect each other. I have tried this with 3 different phones so I know it's not a hardware issue.  In the image below, I should see the other phone pop up on the list but when I run "Scan" on both devices, each screen pops up with a long list of devices in the area that doesn't include the other device.  I have also tried pressing "Scan" on just one of the phones at a time, and I have done all of the above both while the phones are already paired over Bluetooth and while they are not already paired.

I have not changed [Google's code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt). Looking through the library, it seems that the `DeviceScanActivity.java` file is probably where the issue is occurring:

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Activity for scanning and displaying available Bluetooth LE devices.
 */
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
        if (mScanning) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your devices support Bluetooth LE multi broadcast.

Many devices support Bluetooth LE but not the multi broadcast feature.

You can install [Beacon Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.alea.beaconsimulator) to be sure this feature is supported.
If yes, you should start the simulator to be discoverable.

See also this link
[Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/)